# Imputation after one hot encoding in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, data-preprocessing

I have a dataset where I have categorical and numerical data. I want to -

1. Apply OneHot encoding for all categorical columns
2. Use the numerical data + one-hot encoded categorical data to do `Multiple Imputation` using IterativeImputer.
3. Integrate it to a pipeline where I have access to `fit` and `transform` methods.

I can use `ColumnTransformer` to impute using only numerical columns but I want to use the categorical column too for the imputation.

E.g.

```py
sample_data = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [4.4, 1.0, None, 3.0, 2.7],
    "b": ["HIGH", "HIGH", "LOW", "HIGH", "LOW"],
    "c": [True, False, False, True, False]
})
```

I want to first encoded columns `b,c` and then use them along with `a` to impute the missing value in column `a`.

Also, I do not have any missing values in the categorical columns.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os

import pandas as pd
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

load_dotenv()


sample_data = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [4.4, 1.0, None, 3.0, 2.7],
    "a1": [1, 2, 4, None, 2.7],
    "b": ["HIGH", "HIGH", "LOW", "HIGH", "LOW"],
    "c": [True, False, False, True, False]
})


class VTEAllColImputeTransformer(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, non_num_cols=[], num_cols=[]):
        self.non_num_cols = non_num_cols
        self.num_cols = num_cols
        self.encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', drop='first', sparse=False)
        self.num_transformer = IterativeImputer(max_iter=100, random_state=int(os.getenv("RANDOM_SEED")))

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.encoder.fit(X[self.non_num_cols])
        res = pd.DataFrame(self.encoder.transform(X[self.non_num_cols]), columns=self.encoder.get_feature_names_out())
        res = pd.concat([res.reset_index(drop=True), X[self.num_cols].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
        print(res)
        self.num_transformer.fit(res)
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        res = pd.DataFrame(self.encoder.transform(X[self.non_num_cols]), columns=self.encoder.get_feature_names_out())
        res = pd.concat([res.reset_index(drop=True), X[self.num_cols].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
        res = pd.DataFrame(self.num_transformer.transform(res), columns=self.num_transformer.get_feature_names_out())
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        res[self.num_cols] = scaler.fit_transform(res[self.num_cols])
        return res.to_numpy()


custom_transfomer = Pipeline(steps=[('custom_transformer', AllColImputeTransformer(non_num_cols=["b", "c"],
                                                                                      num_cols=["a", "a1"]))])
scaler = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler())])

transformers = []
transformers.append(('custom', custom_transfomer, ["b", "c", "a", "a1"]))

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=transformers)
pre_processing_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor)])
print(pre_processing_pipeline.fit_transform(sample_data))
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to first create pipeline that uses `'ColumnTransformer'` then  apply one-hot encoding to the categorical columns, followed by an `IterativeImputer` that uses both the one-hot encoded categorical columns and numerical columns to impute missing values

```
categorical_transformer = make_pipeline(OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
numerical_transformer = make_pipeline(VarianceThreshold(), StandardScaler(), IterativeImputer())


preprocessor = make_column_transformer(
    (categorical_transformer, make_column_selector(dtype_include=object)),
    (numerical_transformer, make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number))
)

pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessor)

transformed_data = pipeline.fit_transform(sample_data)
```

Comment: I am not able to access the columns from the categorical transformation output in the numerical transformer.